# Citrix receiver SSL connection error. Certificates?

Tags: 17.10, ssl, citrix

I can't get the Citrix Receiver to work on Ubuntu 17.10. (SSL connection couldn't be established)

I tried different versions and copying the certificates from Mozilla as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830127/citrix-receiver-ssl-connection-couldnt-be-established) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970664/citrix-ica-receiver-on-ubuntu-17-10/998711#998711) and ran ctx_rehash.
Another [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302188/certificate-error-when-using-citrix-receiver/971510#971510) suggests to convert a .crt file to .pem.

It's not clear to me though which file is meant and how to get it. I connected to citrix via browser (which works), exported the certificate from the page info/security, converted it to .pem and rehashed. Doesn't work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to connect by exporting the certificate manually from the browser:

- go to the citrix site
- view certificate
- export the certificate. the correct one is one above the actual adress
- convert from .crt to .pem
- rehash

Answer (score 7):

You should simply re-use the certificates already installed with the `ca-certificates` package, e.g. (run these commands in your terminal)

```
cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/
sudo rm -r cacerts
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs cacerts
```

No conversion and rehashing needed.

See [Citrix receiver 13.10 on Ubuntu 18.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064452/citrix-receiver-13-10-on-ubuntu-18-04-1/1069929#1069929) for background reading (and why this is safe).

Comment: This is simplest answer for the given citrix problem. I don't know how lengthy and confusing answers are there on the internet. One must bookmark this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. And also tried to copy the certificates to /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts. I know the certificates work because I need them for browsing the internet (corporate firewall). Firefox and Chromium accept the certificates. Using openssl I found out that the certificates were already in pem format.

When making a connection to the Citrix storefront web page, I don't have a problem. The session starts fine.

edit:

The line below fixed it for me.

$ sudo c_rehash /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/

Comment: OP indicated they rehashed without success.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when using DoD card. 
I found [this](https://www.hagensieker.com/wordpress/2018/07/10/dod-cac-card-on-ubuntu-linux/) website, please look at comment from Jan 4, 2020 - as they have new information.

Shortly:

1. Install pcsc
2. Install openSC (both 1 and 2 from synaptic)
3. In Firefox: preferences--> privacy&security --> Security devices --> load

Give name to your module. Then browse to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/ and load the opensc-pkcs11.so file.
After that things should work without an issue.